# Problem with my passport

Tags: germany, residency

I am married to an EU spouse and living in Germany. I have my residence permit already. I traveled to my country of citizenship but when I tried to go back to Germany they said I can't fly. They said I should come to their consulate. I went there and after they verified my residence permit, they interviewed me.

They said I need to fill out a re-entry visa form which I did. They also said I must get a new passport. They kept my residence permit. They said they would give me a re-entry visa and when I got to Germany, I should apply for another residence permit. My residence permit was ordinary paper and they said I would get a plastic residence permit. I am worried whether they will give me the re-entry visa.

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Please clarify your question as best you can.

Comment: Your edit has provided useful addditional detail, but it's still not clear to me what your actual question is. You've told us what happened, but what is it you want to know from us?

Comment: "But I was worry if they going to give me the reentry visa": is your question whether they will give you the visa? If so, the best answer anyone can give you is "yes," because "they said they would give me a reentry visa." We can't predict the future, but consular staff generally don't lie about consular matters such as this. If your question is something else, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but perhaps this will help.

If you are **currently** married to an EU citizen working in Germany, you are probably entitled to an [Aufenthaltskarte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufenthaltskarte_%28Deutschland%29). In 2011 there was a change from a [paper](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Aufenthaltskarte-vorderseite.jpg&filetimestamp=20101119160932&) format to a [plastic card](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Aufenthaltskarte.JPG). Did you have the old paper card? Then you need a new plastic card. Getting one should be no problem if the family situation is still the same.

Comment: But it appears that because the OP is outside Germany, he must first get a visa so he can enter Germany to get the card.  Of course, your last sentence is just as true of such a visa as it is of the plastic card.

Comment: Getting it should be no problem if he qualified for an Anfenthaltskarte before and nothing has changed. I guess he needs somebody to translate the forms for him.